# Buffering/extrusion of a dem surface

Tags: dem, geometry, algorithm

I have a surface representing a DEM and i would like to add it some thickness. If i simply duplicate the surface and translate it down by my thickness, i get non uniform thickness, ie thinner where the slopes are. I need constant thickness all along the surface.

I am thinking i need to perform some buffering/extrusion of the surface. I started working out some algorithm by dividing my mesh into triangles, taking the normal from the center and creating a new point at the thickness distance. I am a bit stuck on merging those points...

Is there a library/algorithm out there, preferrably in Java, that i could use to achieve the above?

Comment: Hi Thomas, I have to admit that I'm a little unclear about what exactly you're trying to do. Can you try to clarify your question a little? Are you just trying to add a constant elevation to the DEM surface across the entire DEM? By thickness, do you mean a vertical height difference?

Comment: Hi, yes, something akin of the solidify function in Blender (just found that), which takes a thin (no thickness surface) and gives it some volume, some kind of generalised extrusion if that makes any sense? Not sure it is relevant to the gis forum anymore, more of a 3d question really.